# Write permission when mounting Windows shares from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, network-shares, samba, cifs

I think I'm close to having my dev environment set up exactly the way I want, but one final snag remains. I'm running VirtualBox on a Windows 7 x64 host, with my dev enviroment inside a Ubuntu 12.04 guest. I want to keep the files for my projects on the host filesystem - partly so I can access them when the Ubuntu guest is not running, but also so I can use Tortoise and other Windows based tools (*cough* Photoshop), and it also eases my backup scheme somewhat.

So I've got a folder "Rails" on my NTFS drive, which I've shared from the host with a user specifically created for the Ubuntu guest. The mount point has been set up and an entry added to fstab (cifs), using a credentials file and the options `iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=07‌​77` This mounts fine and my Ubuntu user has both read and write permissions to the contents, but when I try to start my Rails app I get permission errors on any files the app needs to write to (e.g. the log file). What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was simply looking in the wrong place - I had forgotten that the account on the Windows host needed to have correct access permissions set on the shared folder; it only had `Read & execute`, `Write` and `List folder contents`. Doh! Adding `Modify` fixed the problem. So nothing but a silly mistake - but I also learned a bit more about the [cifs syntax](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) and `fstab` and figured out how to mount as a humble user, allowing the mount points to be in my `/home/user` folder. The final mount string in my fstab looks like this (my values replaced with [tokens]):

```
//[server]/[share] /home/[user]/[folder] cifs credentials=/home/[user]/.config/samba/.[server],uid=[user],gid=[group] 0 0
```

So you only need to set `uid` and `gid` to the user and group that you want to own the files on the share after mounting - no need for anything else. I also put the Windows user credentials needed in a separate file under my .config dir and did `chmod 400` to stop others from reading it.

It took a surprisingly long time to figure all this out as there are a million arguments to use with cifs, and many seem to have misunderstood them - so many people recommend using `file_mode`/`dir_mode` 777 (which sounds like a really bad idea to me), and pepper with unnecessary arguments like `nounix`, `noperm`, `rw`, `iocharset` and `noacl` - none of which are needed to make this work. So while my problem was caused by a simple mistake I'll leave the question (and this answer) here; hopefully someone will find it helpful!

**Edit:** Due to [a bug in Samba's cifs implementation](http://bugs.debian.org/483507) it is necessary to add the `nobrl` option as well if you intend to run SQLite databases on the share. Basically, the current Samba cifs Linux client cannot handle the way SQLite locks the database file. Not a great solution, and almost certainly a bad idea in a multi user environment but since in my case it's a single user share, and hosted on the same machine as the client (which should all but eliminate network latency), I'm gonna roll with it.

> **nobrl**
>
> Do not send byte range lock requests to the server. This is necessary
>   for certain applications that break with cifs style mandatory byte
>   range locks (and most cifs servers do not yet support requesting
>   advisory byte range locks).

The fstab entry now looks like this:

```
//[server]/[share] /home/[user]/[folder] cifs nobrl,credentials=/home/[user]/.config/samba/.[server],uid=[user],gid=[group] 0 0
```